# How to keep track of navigation in my angularjs tree implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, treeview

I have implemented a tree using ng-include directive as show in at the end, but I can't keep track of the parent child relationship some how so I need some help.

For the following kind of data it displays a tree in the image, I want the active or clicked node to return me some text like

GrandFather -> Father -> ActiveItem

How can I do that?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="treeLevel.html">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <button ng-click="show=!show" class="badge success" id="itemSelection"
                ng-model="item._Selected"
                ui-sref="resourceDefault.clicked({energyId:item.energyId, energyChain:item.energyChain,resourceId:item.resourceId,facilityId:item.facilityId})">
                {{item.name}}
            </button>
            <div ng-include=" 'treeLevel.html'"
                onload="items = item.children" ng-show="!show">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

The Data the tree uses and its out put

```
$scope.resourceItems = [{
    name: "Resource",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Hydro",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Basin",
                    energyId: "3",
                    energyChain: "12",
                    resourceId: "12",
                    facilityId: "12"
                },
                {
                    name: "Abbay 20",
                    energyId: "3",
                    energyChain: "12",
                    resourceId: "12",
                    facilityId: "12"
                },
                {
                    name: "Abbay 21",
                    energyId: "3",
                    energyChain: "12",
                    resourceId: "12",
                    facilityId: "12"
                },
                {
                    name: "Abbay 22",
                    energyId: "3",
                    energyChain: "12",
                    resourceId: "12",
                    facilityId: "12"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "wind",
            energyId: "3",
            energyChain: "12",
            resourceId: "12",
            facilityId: "12"
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: "Primary Energy",
    energyId: "3",
    energyChain: "12",
    resourceId: "12",
    facilityId: "12"
},
{
    name: "Secondary Energy",
    energyId: "3",
    energyChain: "12",
    resourceId: "12",
    facilityId: "12"
},
{
    name: "Transport",
    energyId: "3",
    energyChain: "12",
    resourceId: "12",
    facilityId: "12"
},
{
    name: "Consumption",
    energyId: "3",
    energyChain: "12",
    resourceId: "12",
    facilityId: "12"
}];
```

The output of the tree:

[image]

Comment: why not just use ng-click on the nodes? and execute some function which returns some text or shows a breadcrumb somewhere

Comment: yes offcourse I have done that ,I can get the current node like for example  when "Abbay 20" clicked but I want to display                                      " Resource -> Hydro ->Abbay 20" when " Abbay 20 " is clicked but now in the ngClick function how can i get the two father nodes programmatically? that what i want to ask. tnks